# stick polar chart to restricted area inside the chart

Tags: highcharts

I'm trying to restrict shown polar chart not to be drawn above the slices labels.
I tried pane.size and it worked with [example1](https://jsfiddle.net/g40kedxo)
, but when series data changed it didn't work, see [example2](https://jsfiddle.net/7Lp58e49), any help?

See this [example1](https://jsfiddle.net/g40kedxo), slice3 (red color) at the edge

and in [example2](https://jsfiddle.net/7Lp58e49) same config but different series data, slice3 (red color) not at the edge.

I need to force slice3 in example2 to be at the edge like in example1

`enter code here`

Sample polar chart

[image: 1]

Comment: Hi, could you share a simplified example in the online code editor? Please describe in more detail what do you want to achieve, what means this marked green area?

Comment: Can you please share your config details? Pane.size should limit the area of all panes.

Comment: Thanks for replying! I've add more details and examples to explain it more.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

set yAxis.endOnTick=false did the magic, [working sample](https://jsfiddle.net/bq38jLfk/)

```
yAxis: {
    endOnTick: false
}
```